# What are the prerequisites to study topological quantum computation/topological phases of the matter?

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer, topological-insulators

I am an undergraduate student and I would like to approach the subject of topological order with focus on topological quantum computation, I know (very) little QFT and basic algebraic topology (if that matters...).

To give a reference frame, I'd like to understand papers like http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021  or Preskill's great presentations: http://online.kitp.ucsb.edu/online/exotic_c04/preskill/, and later to take it as my field of research for a PhD.

So my questions are:

1. What kind of studies are useful/needed for this field? I assume Quantum Computation/Information are, but what else? Quantum Field Theories, Topology, Quantum Optics?
2. Which are universities or research centers active in the field (preferably in Europe)?
3. Any reference suggested? (Better if beginner-focused)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)

Comment: Note also that question (4) is entirely opinion-based which is off-topic here.

Comment: Do you think that question 4) is opinion-based, or the whole question? In the first case I will simply remove it.

Comment: Actually, I meant 3 specifically but typed 4 by accident. But looking further at these, I think all of them are really opinion-based.